# Is there a way to run apollo-server and nextjs at the same time with Vercel?

Tags: next.js, apollo-server, vercel

I can't seem to run my apollo-server at the same time I deploy/run (npm run dev) with NextJs. I've tried below and it doesn't work because it gets stuck sitting at apollo server and waiting for GET and POST requests, and same with NextJs which makes sense by their nature didn't know if there was a way to run both on the same server, also I've tried deploying apollo-server to lambda and straight to a server and no luck. Thanks in advance!

```
node server & next dev
```

Comment: is your usecase to deploy at the same instant ? how about running the commands separately in 2 different shells ?

Comment: What I ended up doing was just getting another EC2 instance to run the server itself for apollo-server and running the next js part on Vercel itself

Comment: Another thing that could be used to that I use with the apollo server stuff if you have access to the linux distro is running [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) which allows you to run and keep running your commands to host the node like applications